# Append data to existing file in Azure Data Lake storage from REST API

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have set up pipeline that fetch data from REST API and drops it down into ADLS storage gen1 , I am also seeing the files generated

**REST API > ADF pipeline(get bearer token + Copy activity) > ADLS**

But when new data comes in from that API , data is replacing the current content in that file  instead of appending at the last line every time

is there any dynamic action that i need to provide or something ? can someone please put me in right direction .

Note: i can able to see the content inside the file , no errors at all

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of Blob storage, I don't think this is possible with a standard Copy activity. Azure Blobs have several types, the most common of which is BlockBlob, which is almost surely the type generated by ADF operations. A BlockBlob cannot be changed or updated, only overwritten, which explains the behavior you are experiencing. In order to update the content of a blob, it must be defined as an AppendBlob, which permits adding new content. The AppendBlob type must be declared when the Blob is created.

The only way I know to accomplish this (both creating the AppendBlob and appending content to it) is via the Azure Storage SDK, which includes classes and methods specific to dealing with AppendBlobs. This operation would require some custom code (I'll assume a C# console app) to access the storage account and append to the Blob. In order to incorporate this into your pipeline, you will need to replace your Copy activity with a Custom activity, which will execute your C# code in an Azure Batch account.

An alternative to consider is permitting the Copy activity to generate a new blob every time instead of trying to work with a single Blob. Data lakes and MPPs in general are designed to work with many files at a time, so depending on your use case that may be a more reasonable approach.